# Can I fix my Park Tool CCP-22 - the round head came off?

Tags: tools

At some point I somehow managed to break my crank puller. The round head that pushes against the axle has come off.

Can I get a replacement handle / fix it myself or do I just need to buy a new tool?

[image]

Comment: I doubt that replacement parts are available.  A machinist might be able to drill holes to allow the cap to be screwed on, but the effort is probably not worth it.

Comment: Park offer a limited lifetime [warranty](https://www.parktool.com/form/warranty) and I assume this would constitute a defect, but also counts on having the proof of purchase... and who keeps those amirite!?

Comment: Given they seem to be about $15 US at various online US retailers, the cost to repair is probably more than just buying a new one.

Comment: Did it break during normal usage as a crank puller?  Or were you using it for something else outside the design intent?

Comment: no criggie. I swear I respect my bike tools! I can't say the some for the general tools though. I must of dropped it at some point or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would contact Park Tool's customer service and inquire about warranty replacement.  Their hand tools have a lifetime warranty against manufacturer defects to the original purchaser.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this could be a good excuse to buy a new bike with two piece cranks, so you that you won’t need that crank puller.

Sincerely,

The Bike Industry

Comment: i just spent just under a grand on full suspension my parents are going to kill me.

Comment: Down-voted by a crank.